# PHP redirect users

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, content-management-system

I am developing a custom CMS in CORE PHP for college project. Obviously I've tons of files and folders. And I need help with redirecting users whenever they fire a template page.
Here's the file structure of project

```
Project
    | assets
        | css +js stuff
    | template
        | - header.php
        | - footer.php
        | - navigation.php
        | ---
    | - index.php
    | - login.php
    | ---
```

Now what my question: I want to redirect user if user directly fire `project.com/template/header.php` . same with `naviation.php` `footer` and other template files. Is there any `.htaccess` work around or a function to handle this functionality.?

I am okay to create an error or 404 page for redirecting user.

Comment: Why don't you put the files, you don't want your visitors to access, outside the httpdocs root?

Comment: I don't visitors to directly fire header or navigation file in url. For the obvious reason it will show them error. However I didn't placed the direct urls of header/footer/navigation anywhere. So user won't be able to know file structure of it. But still

Comment: Are you aware of Code Igniter PHP Framework?

Comment: @JaiminVyas I do! But I am not using any :)

Comment: @zipal_ Code Igniter provide route.php inbuilt library that you redirect automatically to you specific pah.

Comment: I know Code Igniter provides this functionality but I am not using any framework,

Answer (score 2):

You can include the something like the following in any page to which you do not want direct access

```
if ( realpath(__FILE__) == realpath( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', TRUE, 404 );
    die( header( 'location: error.php?code=404' ) );
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! But still any better way to handle this situation.?

Comment: you could set up some rules in your htaccess file that prevent access to the `template` directory and it's files

Answer (score 0):

You can create one define, at the start of valid page
then in templates pages you start wiith testing if value defined
if not redirect to index.php

```
define('TOKEN', true);
...
if (!defined('TOKEN')) {
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via .htaccess file

Create .htaccess file and insert the below lines to that file then move that file to your root folder.

```
Redirect 301 /header.php http://www.yourdomain.com/404.php
Redirect 301 /footer.php http://www.yourdomain.com/404.php
Redirect 301 /navigation.php http://www.yourdomain.com/404.php
```